# Inappropriate value for attribute cidr_blocks: element 0: string required

Tags: terraform

Trying to upgrade a module to V12. I am currently getting the above error. Question is, can i define a map list in the module rather than declaring as a variable ?

security_groups = [
module.ecs.asg_security_group_id,
aws_security_group.default_security_group.id,
aws_security_group.custom_security_group.id,
aws_security_group.pa_security_group.id,
aws_security_group.mashery_security_group.*.id,
]

If so, how can i go about this, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

aws_security_group.mashery_security_group.*.id returns list.
flatten function will help in this case.

```tf
security_groups = flatten([ module.ecs.asg_security_group_id, aws_security_group.default_security_group.id, aws_security_group.custom_security_group.id, aws_security_group.pa_security_group.id, aws_security_group.mashery_security_group.*.id, ])
```